# QUnit doesn't print any results

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I have the most basic examples of a test runner page shown on the QUnit page inserted into an MVC project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>QUnit basic example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/qunit-1.11.0.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Div1"></div>
  <div id="Div2"></div>
  <script src="../Scripts/qunit-1.11.0.js"></script>
  <script>
      test("a basic test example", function () {
          var value = "hello";
          equal(value, "hello", "We expect value to be hello");
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this, I just see a blank page. The tests execute as they stop on a breakpoint. Links to the .css and .js are correct and working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem with MVC and fixed it by getting the source files from the qunit website rather than relying on nuget. After i did this, it all worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, I was experiencing this problem and your suggestion fixed it for me too.  Thanks for saving me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 3):

The two divs must have the following ids, because QUnit is looking for these to display anything.

```
 <div id="qunit"></div>
 <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
```

Comment: I also tried the other simple example found on their homepage which has exactly that for the divs , same result unfortunately.

Comment: That's very strange... I've created a jsfiddle demo that reproduces your test, and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/gustavohenke/jb8a9/

Answer (score 2):

**QUnit for ASP.Net MVC** requires something a little different. Instead of the normal qunit and qunit-fixture divs, use something like this:

```
<div>
    <h1 id="qunit-header">QUnit Test Results</h1>
    <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
</div>
```

For a full example, see [Unit Testing JavaScript/JQuery in ASP.Net MVC Project using QUnit Step by Step](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranab/archive/2013/06/20/unit-testing-javascript-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc-project-using-qunit.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me.  I prefer this solution to the other, because it allows me to do testing without an internet connection.

Comment: This should be the answer as this question relates to QUnit for ASP.Net MVC!